# Create mobile css for table structured website or create a proper structure?

Tags: html, css

Someone asked me to create a mobile version of [this website](http://tsjechie-slowakije.nl/).
mobile websites is sort of a new subject for me and I'm wondering if I should use media tags on the old structure or not. The whole website is one big table... Is it even possible to do it with just css with a table website?

I'm getting css rules like this which in my opinion is not the way to go:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

    body > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: well it's possible to do it with CSS but it's messy . if you have the time and if you want, you could change the HTML structure of the current website using bootstrap . if not, good luck with media queries :)

Comment: @MihaiT But bootstrap uses media queries as well right? the only difference is that it is a pain do do it myself?

Comment: yeah. i meant that with the current HTML structure ( tables inside tables ) it will be very time consuming and frustrating to write media-queries. besides, i think that the site owner would like to get into the XXI century and have a modern structure on the site. ( don't forget to charge more ! )

Comment: @MihaiT hmm ok I'll try learning bootstrap. Thx for the help:)